# apache ant increase memory and speed

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant

I have many applications which are run using ANT

I would like to increase the amount of RAM allocated to ANT to speed up my programs.
What are the best practices to do it and speed up the development setup for mostly J2EE applications?

Comment: Was my answer useful? If you up-vote and accept useful answers people will be more motivated to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set usual  [java memory options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html) like Xmx by setting ANT_OPTS environment variable.

I doubt that it will speed up your build.

But you can always try.